# Visual Studio - Space after auto filling word

Tags: c#, visual-studio

recently moved over to visual studio
When I start typing a word, let's say "Tex" I get the popup with possible auto-fillings, and if I press enter, it automatically changes it to "TextBox"
The problem I have is, whenever I do that, I have to press 'space' to start typing the next word, something that get's pretty annoying if you type 10,000 words..

Is there an easy way to make the typing start one space after the autofilled word?

Thank you in advance :)
Pic1: http://prntscr.com/fbpzdq
Pic2: http://prntscr.com/fbpzlc

Comment: You not always want a space after a word. Often you want a dot ".". Ex.: `person.FirstName.Length`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecfczya1(v=vs.100).aspx should have your answer.  Found by googling "visual studio intellisense autocomplete".

Comment: Sure.  You can write your own IDE and define all its behaviors yourself.  But (smirk) what language would you write it in?

Comment: @ScottMermelstein  that page is for VS2010 and prior.  Feature's gone in VS2017.

Comment: @XavierJ OP hasn't specified version, but the [equivalent page for 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-intellisense) is referenced in the documents for VS 2015.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Whitespace is allowed on either side of the `.` character, Ex: `person .    FirstName    .  Length` (with tabs and spaces) compiles and runs just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can simply use the `Spacebar` to perform the auto-complete instead of pressing `Enter`. Both methods finish the completion of the word, but using the `Spacebar` will also add a space after the word.

It even works when using the `"."` character after a name; you still get the intellisense list of object members to choose from, and auto complete will magically remove the space(s) when you type a `;` or closing brace `}`, or any other character that triggers line formatting.

**Example**

```
// This is what it looks like while typing, using Spacebar to complete the words
this .textBox1 .Text = "hello" 

// And then as soon as the `;` is added, it's all fixed:
this.textBox1.Text = "hello";
```

And, for what it's worth, whitespace is allowed on either side of the `.` between an object and it's members. So even if the spaces were left as in the first example, the code still compiles and runs just fine.